# youtube-dl playlist does not work anymore

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-dl, playlist

in the past I have downloaded Youtube's playlists with *youtube-dl* without any problem. However, now it downloads 0 videos. Could it have something to do with RIAA's DMCA takedown? Any suggestion or solution?
The code I usually use is

```
youtube-dl -i -f mp4 --write-auto-sub --yes-playlist --output './%(title)s.%(ext)s' UUdp4_l1vPmpN-gDbUwhaRUQ
```

I have tried with the web URL or the playlist ID, both give me this result:

```
[youtube:playlist] UUdp4_l1vPmpN-gDbUwhaRUQ: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: UUdp4_l1vPmpN-gDbUwhaRUQ
[youtube:playlist] playlist UUdp4_l1vPmpN-gDbUwhaRUQ: Downloading 0 videos
[download] Finished downloading playlist: UUdp4_l1vPmpN-gDbUwhaRUQ
```

Also, I have uninstalled/updated youtube-dl (just in case) without improve.
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an issue with youtube-dl, however the youtube-dlc fork [has already fixed it](https://github.com/blackjack4494/yt-dlc/issues/148).

You can download directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/blackjack4494/yt-dlc) or else download it with pip:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade youtube-dlc
```

**UPDATE**: youtube-dl [has been restored](https://github.blog/2020-11-16-standing-up-for-developers-youtube-dl-is-back/).

Answer (score 0):

I was on windows and with youtube-dl -U parameter updated version suddenly did not work on playlists. Then I manually loaded the update directly from http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html.
Manually loaded had different size( 7894k ) but same version. 2020.11.24
Update by -U paramater had size 7842k.
Thing was for example that command line updated -U version did not understand playlist title:
'%(playlist_title)s/
In the target directory playlist name was was always NA.
Immediately all started work like old days with manually loaded version.

Comment: I am glad it worked. It seems that since Github [stood up for developers] [1] this problem is solved. I could download any playlist with: youtube-dl --yes-playlist 'URL' 
[1]: https://github.blog/2020-11-16-standing-up-for-developers-youtube-dl-is-back/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now and was able to resolve it by updating the install.

`sudo youtube-dl -U` for linux.

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl stopped working again
it looks like the response from you tube is base64 encoded

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).